# How to combine multiple SQL SELECT results into one array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hello this code works but currently it is very repetitive.

I have been trying for a few days now, and I just cannot work out how to rewrite these separate SELECTs into one loop using arrays.

I would like to push about 20 entries, so if I cannot work out how to do the loop then its going to messy! :(

I would be grateful for any help with the first loop and from that I will try and solve the rest myself from that advice, Thanks..

```
                // Create 6 random numbers from table
                $ran_num = (RandomInRange(1,$total,6));

                // Select data from table from a random row
                $grab1 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[0]'";
                $grab2 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[1]'";
                $grab3 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[2]'";
                $grab4 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[3]'";
                $grab5 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[4]'";
                $grab6 = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[5]'";

                $result1 = $mysqli->query($grab1);
                $result2 = $mysqli->query($grab2);
                $result3 = $mysqli->query($grab3);
                $result4 = $mysqli->query($grab4);
                $result5 = $mysqli->query($grab5);
                $result6 = $mysqli->query($grab6);

                // Convert result into an array called items
                $item1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
                $item2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
                $item3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);
                $item4 = mysqli_fetch_row($result4);
                $item5 = mysqli_fetch_row($result5);
                $item6 = mysqli_fetch_row($result6);
```

I managed to solve this with help on this thread..
I replaced all this code with:

```
                // Create 6 random numbers from table
                $ran_num = (RandomInRange(1,$total,6));

                foreach ($ran_num as $key => $value) {
                  $grab[$key] = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$value'";
                  $result = $mysqli->query($grab[$key]);
                  $item[$key] = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                }
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: [`IN()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)?

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (in the notes you have how to use foreach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ran_num = (RandomInRange(1,$total,6));
    foreach ($ran_num as $key => $value)
        {
            $grab[$value] = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$value'";
        }
?>
```

If you don't need to access each statement individually, this is also possible:

```
<?php
    $ran_num = (RandomInRange(1,$total,6));
    $grab = '';
    foreach ($ran_num as $key => $value)
        {
            $grab .= "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$value';";
        }
?>
```

That's essentially creating one long string that SQL will parse as individual commands using the semi-colon as the delimiter for each one.

Comment: Thank you, This also looks like exactly what I've been trying to achieve. I will also have a play around with this and try to learn from it.

Comment: This very nearly works but I don't want the grab to be the same as $value, I want grab to increment by 1 each time from 0. Is this possible?

Comment: I changed grab[$value] to grab[$key] and I think it works, May not be right way to go about it though.

Comment: So, in your example, you are accessing the array values, not the array keys. If you are changing to `grab[$key]`, then you're using the keys, which are just 0 through whatever random number is chosen. If `$ran_num` is an array like so: [ 0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, etc.] then it shouldn't matter. I don't know what the function `RandomInRange` does, so I can't explain why `grab[$value]` isn't working for you, when that's what you're doing in your example.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you *really* need `*`?

What's wrong with using a single query with the [`IN()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) function? For example:

```
// Create 6 random numbers from table
$ran_num = (RandomInRange(1,$total,6));

// Select(grab) data from table from a random row
$grab = 'SELECT * FROM stock_tbl WHERE stock_id IN ('.implode(',', $ran_num).')';
```

Comment: I am select all data from the data base so the * is needed for this. I'll do some reading into the IN() function and see what I can learn from that, Thank you

Comment: @Mike You may be selecting all of the columns, but do you really need them all later?

Comment: I do, I'm recalling them to display different information in a stock gallery chosen from random items of stock. Item name, Description, Price etc

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings in PHP with the '.' operator. Also, setting the grab variables as an array will make this easier as well, if that is possible in your implementation. You're probably looking for code such as:

```
for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    $grab[i] = "select * from stock_tbl where stock_id='$ran_num[".i."]'";
```

Comment: Yes the idea was to use the grab as an array.

I think this is the road I need to go down, I'll have a little play around with this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you need it as an array? Are you ultimately running the queries?

Comment: Sorry I will be running the queries but I didn't include the extra code as I didn't want to ask too much at once and I was hoping I would work the rest out myself from advice on the first loop. I have updated my original question to hopefully explain myself better. Thank you